# Hiding xfce4-panel from command line

Tags: bash, xfce

Is there a way to hide xfce4-panel from command line. If no any other solutions how to hide it from terminal ?

Regards,
Levon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got here wondering the same. Apparently there is no direct command, but it's pretty straightforward to write a shell script:

```
INFO=$(xwininfo -name xfce4-panel)
STATE=$(echo "$INFO" | grep "Map State:" | head -n1 | awk -F: '{print $2}' | xargs)
WID=$(echo "$INFO" | grep "Window id:" | head -n1 | awk -F: '{print $3}' | awk '{print $1}')
if test "$STATE" = "IsViewable"; then
  xdotool windowminimize "$WID"
else
  xdotool windowmap "$WID"
fi
```